# How show external list in custom quick launch heading

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

can anyone explain me how i can do that:

I want create external content type in SP Designer 2010 and list based on this external content type. By default this list will appear in "Lists" heading in quick launch, but i want create my custom heading, for example "My external types" and show some external lists in that heading rather than "Lists" heading.

Is that possible?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just edit quick launch: Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Quick Launch (Look and feel).
http://www.hosting.com/support/sharepoint-2010/add-edit-or-delete-a-quick-launch-heading

Comment: Thanks for answer, can i add any list to this new heading? I cann't find how to do it.

Comment: Sorry for my inattention, "New Navigation link" and choose heading for new link.